# The difference between blowing up subvarieties one by one and simultaneously

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a variety defined over a field $k$ and it has irreducible subvarieties $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, whose intersection is nonempty. There are three ways to do blowing up,

1. Blow up $Y_1$, and then blow up the proper transform of $Y_2$.
2. Blow up $Y_2$, and then blow up the proper transform of $Y_1$.
3. Blow up $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ simultaneously.

Are they always isomorphic? If not, could their differences by characterised?

Comment: They are not isomorphic in general, for example if $Y_1 \subset Y_2$ then 1. and 3. have different Chow ring.